# JMeter: Parse JSON and count

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter to test a web application.  The application returns JSON that looks like the following:

```
{"type":"8","id":"2093638401"}
{"type":"9","id":"20843301"}
{"type":"14","id":"20564501"}
```

I need to get a count based on type.

I have tried adding foreach controller with a regular expression extractor, but Im not sure I have done it correctly:

- Apply to: Main sample only
- Response field to check: Body
- Reference name: match_type
- Regular Expression: "type":"(\d)"
- Template: $1$
- Match no.: -1

Im new to JMeter so Im not sure if Im doing any of this correctly.

Thanks

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "I need to get a count based on type." ?

Comment: That's not really JSON. Is it actually a JSON array (e.g.,  `[{"type":"8","id":"23324"},{"type":"42","id":"22224"}]`)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to operate on both type and id in single sampler, I think simple regex and `ForEach` controller won't be sufficient. You will have to write two regex extractor followed by while controller with `BSF processor` (javascript or beanshell) to extract both the values and export them to jmeter variable. Something of following type

```
- First Request
  - Regex extractor for type
  - Regex extractor for id
  - BSF processor (to initialize the loopcount=0 and the total_matches of matches that you found)
- while controller (loopcount < total_matches)
  - BSF processor 
     - export/set current_type = type_$loopcount
     - export/set current_id = id_$loopcount
     - increment loopcount
  - USE current_type and current_id in whatever sampler you like
```

== Update ==

This http://goo.gl/w3u1r tutorial depicts exactly how to go about it.